# Clear Default not enabled in 4.0

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, default-applications

I'm trying to set Chrome as my default browser but cannot. I go to apps and the clear default button is not enabled and says no default is set.

Comment: Are you looking at the `Clear Defaults` button on Chrome or the built-in browser application? Chrome's button won't be enabled because it isn't the default, you have to find the button on your *current* default browser so that you can unset it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to go via your browser (Chrome, or some other browser in this case) to reset your default app settings though, you can do this from Settings > Apps. Click the "settings" dots in the top right hand corner and then choose "Reset app preferences". Your phone will now reset all app preferences and start asking you again what browser to use.

[image: Choose "Apps"]

[image: Choose "Reset app preferences"]

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with Android 4.4 and Huawei's Emotional UI. *Clear Defaults* is disabled (greyed out) from built-in apps such as Browser and Music. I can change e.g. music player from `Settings > Manage apps > Default app settings`, but the default browser cannot be changed with that tool. I have a rooted phone, so I ended up removing `/system/priv-app/browser.apk` after installing Chrome.